# Speech bubble info screen

Tags: java, android, user-interface

Is there an easy way to create something like the info "speech-bubble" which is shown by the Google Now Launcher after the first startup (see the image below)?

[image: Google Now Launcher: info screen]

Comment: ... use a very simple 9 patch?

Comment: @Rotwang Is there no default way to achive this without creating a custom image/graphic?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. What's the point in drawing a small triangle? Or you could use a Unicode character. Or a VectorDrawable.